# How to use Perl's grep to find a particular file by matching a pattern in its name

Tags: perl, file, grep, design-patterns, matching

I have a string stored in a Perl variable that should match with the beginning part of a file name stored in a directory.

I use this variable to find the file matching this pattern from the directory, using Perl's grep. Here's what I am doing:

```
    opendir (DIR, "data/testroot/") or die "$!";
    @file1 = <$f1/*.hdf>
    foreach(@file1){
       $patt = substr(basename($_),0,$ind);
       $file2 = grep {/${patt}*\.hdf/} readdir(DIR);
       #other code follows.......
    }
    closedir(DIR);
```

First, I get a list of all files in folder `f1` and storing them in the array `@file`. Then for each entry in `@file1`, I extract the first few characters, store them in `$patt`, then try to pick up similar files from another folder `data/testroot/` which have the matching beginning pattern as stored in `$patt`.

That grep `$file2 = grep {/${patt}*\.hdf/} readdir(DIR);` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to find all `*.hdf` files in directory A whose filenames match the first `$ind` characters of any such file in directory B?

You should use either `glob` or `readdir` for both directories, but not both. In this case `glob` seems to be the best bet as it allows you to select all `*.hdf` files from A without having to check them with the regex.

The program below seems to do what you need. I have substituted sample values for `$f1` and `$ind`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;

my $f1 = 'data';
my $f1 = 'data/testroot';
my $ind = 6;

foreach (glob "$f1/*.hdf") {
  my $patt = substr(basename($_), 0, $ind);
  my @match = glob "$f2/$patt*.hdf";

  #other code follows.......
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you need the grep at all. If `$patt` is just non-specials from the another filename, wouldn't `glob "$patt*.hdf"` do it?

Comment: yeah but `glob` was missing alternate files when run in a loop so I had to fall back on grep

Comment: Also if i do this: `$patt = substr(basename($_),0,$ind); my @file2 = grep { basename($_) =~ /^\Q$patt/ } glob <$f2/*.hdf>;` it does not seem to work. `$_` still retains the first filename read from the first folder `A`. So how do I pipe the output of `glob` to `grep`?. One more thing is it PERL forces me to use `$_` in `basename` otherwise throws error. I am sorry I am kind of noob in PERL so some of my questions may sound silly.

Comment: You should expand your answer to say what you are trying to do (instead of how you are trying to do it). You should also show the input that's giving you problems.

Comment: You can't write `glob <$f2/*.hdf>` as both `glob` and `<...>` are performing globs and it gets into a terrible mess. I would do as *brian de foy* suggests and write `my @file2 = glob "$f2/$patt*.hdf";`. I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`${patt}*\.hdf` means "0 or more occurrences of $patt, followed by .hdf". Are you sure you don't mean "$patt, followed by arbitrary text, followed by .hdf"?

That would be `/${patt}.*\.hdf/`.

Comment: Yes I want to match `${patt}` followed by one or more characters and then `.hdf` so thanks I got that part. But when I change my line as follows: `$file2 = grep {/${patt}.*\.hdf}/} readdir(DIR);` it still does not pick up the file. Something else is going wrong.

Comment: No no sorry my mistake. It works I had an extra `}` in there so that was causing the problem. thanks a lot. I learnt something new.